# Помогите придумать логику

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть код, который считает расход за месяц

```
 $grnEndQuery = "SELECT SUM(number) from costs WHERE MONTH(data) = 
 MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(data) = YEAR(NOW())";
 $grnEndCosts = mysqli_query($conection, $grnEndQuery);         
 $grnEndCosts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grnEndCosts);
 $grnEndCosts = (int)$grnEndCosts['SUM(number)'];
```

Надо как-то придумать, чтоб в конце месяца сохранялся результат за месяц и начинало считаться за новый месяц, помогите придумать как это сделать.
Также есть форма добавления расхода.

Comment: считайте всегда за 2 месяца, предыдущий и текущий (разумеется одним запросом) и сохраняйте в отдельной таблице. ну или скажем первые 2 дня месяца считайте за 2, а потом можно уже за один, так как можно быть боле менее уверенным что предыдущий окончательно рассчитан (если конечно скрипт более чем на 2 дня не перестанет срабатывать).

Comment: мало что понял)

Comment: мне кажется нужно ввести поле дата, в базу, далее брать эту дату и если она больше чем дата +31 день то считать заново.

Comment: А думаете ваш вопрос очень сильно понятен ? например к чему написано, что есть форма добавления расхода, как это относится к расчету. так же не указано как часто и каким образом вы сейчас запускаете этот расчет

Comment: у меня дата есть же она сохранятса timestamp

Comment: как как? Ajax же после каждого добавление считает сразу

Comment: А где в вашем вопросе указано, что это вызывается при обращении из браузера и часто, а не например по крону раз в неделю ? Мы должны как то сами об этом догадаться ? А если так, то вам вообще сумму считать не надо. заводите отдельную таблицу в которой будут хранится месячные суммы. создаете на таблицу costs триггер, который при добавлении/модификации в ней записей добавляет/вычитает значения текущей записи из сумм в таблице с суммами, округляя дату из записи до месяца. (искать на этом сайте и в гугле по слову "триггер")

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1);
```

данный запрос выводит первый день текущего месяца

Для вас текущий месяц:

```
SELECT SUM(number) from costs WHERE data > ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),  
INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1);
```

За прошлый месяц:

```
SELECT SUM(number) 
from costs 
WHERE data BETWEEN 
ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), 1) AND 
ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1);
```